# How to make a condition in a React hook?

Tags: reactjs

how to properly make a condition in a useState hook?

I have this code snippet:

```
  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('Hello');

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setInput((prevInput) => ( 
    (e.target.value.length == 6) && { ...prevInput, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
```

Where is the problem, please, if such a piece of code ends up with an error? And points to a semicolon?

```
Unexpected token, expected "," (9:84)
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you need to do?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `e.target.value.length !== 6`? Because right now, it's going to set `input` to `false` (Which may be desired, but seems a little odd)

Comment: In case `e.target.value.length! == 6` I wanted to return `...prevInput`

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error because you're missing a closing parenthesis `)` in the setInput and a closing bracket for the first arrow function `}`

```
const inputHandler = (e) => {
  setInput(
    (prevInput) =>
      (e.target.value.length === 6 && {
        ...prevInput,
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
      })
  );
};
```

It is worth to mention that this setInput is changing the state from a string to an object or to false if the condition is not met. You should pass the e.target.value to avoid changing the state type.

Comment: That's exactly what caused my problem. Thanks, yes you are right that the syntax is bad (I rewrote the code incorrectly). The problem is that my input field is blocked because the value never reaches 6 characters. Therefore, would it be better to use the ternary operator in this case?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but what are you trying to achieve?